# What does the count for $destroy in $rootScope.$$listenerCount mean?

Tags: angularjs

I couldn't find any specific documentation related to what it means. Is this the count of the listeners destroyed, or is the count of listeners that will be destroyed when $destroy is called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$$listenerCount` is not used by `$destroy`, but rather by `<scope>.broadcast(<eventname>)`.  The count is maintained for performance reasons.  When you perform a broadcast, instead of sending it to all of the child scopes in the hierarchy, it will only propagated to those scopes which actually have listeners specifically listening for that event.

The reason you are seeing it pop up in `$destroy` is because when a scope is destroyed, it will release all of its listeners, but it needs to propagate that decrement `$$listenerCount[<eventname>]` at each parent along the way up to the `$rootScope`.  So, every scope has one of these $$listenerCount collections.  `$rootscope` is a little bit special though in that it cannot actually be destroyed.

Comment: I would point out, as someone else (floribon) on this thread has, that anything with $$ prefixed to it is purely internal, so it could really change at any time.  It's not something we should rely on.  But it is pretty neat to understand how it all works.

Comment: Much more understandable answer, I was just digging into what I could read. Thanks @MichaelHays

Answer (score 1):

Like with many of Angular internals, you need to check the code source to understand it.

Here is the definiton on the `$on` method:

```
$on: function(name, listener) {
  var namedListeners = this.$$listeners[name];
  if (!namedListeners) {
    this.$$listeners[name] = namedListeners = [];
  }
  namedListeners.push(listener);

  var current = this;
  do {
    if (!current.$$listenerCount[name]) {
      current.$$listenerCount[name] = 0;
    }
    current.$$listenerCount[name]++;
  } while ((current = current.$parent));

  var self = this;
  return function() {
    var indexOfListener = namedListeners.indexOf(listener);
    if (indexOfListener !== -1) {
      namedListeners[indexOfListener] = null;
      decrementListenerCount(self, 1, name);
    }
  };
}
```

And here is the `$destroy` method:

```
  $destroy: function() {
    // we can't destroy the root scope or a scope that has been already destroyed
    if (this.$$destroyed) return;
    var parent = this.$parent;

    this.$broadcast('$destroy');
    this.$$destroyed = true;
    if (this === $rootScope) return;

    incrementWatchersCount(this, -this.$$watchersCount);
    for (var eventName in this.$$listenerCount) {
      decrementListenerCount(this, this.$$listenerCount[eventName], eventName);
    }

    // ... blah blah
  }
```

For what I understand, for each scope that registers an event (`$destroy` in your case), the count is incremented by the depth of this scope, and is reset when such scope is destroyed.

Soooo, I would say it actually gives you the number of watchers that will be removed when `$destroy()` is called as per your second suggestion. However I might be wrong: no mortal is supposed to mess up with these deep internals.

Comment: I'll probably have to read that code more, but its at about 1000 count, and if its not useful, I might as well just destroy it to improve performance (I hope it improves performance).

Comment: It is useful, and it is just a number, you wouldn't save any memory by deleting it but could create memory leaks that would be quite more harmful.